# Determining how many table rows are visible on the screen before scroll-bar shows up

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

**Background:** I am working on a dashboard, which shows a header and a table underneath. The table can have many rows (over 100).

**Problem:** large number of rows triggers a vertical scrollbar to show up, which hides the rest of the rows.

**Possible solution:** I would like to rotate, what table rows are showed on every screen the dashboard is on. I would like to avoid to set a fixed number of rows that are visible on screen and instead, determine how many rows can be put on the screen before the scroll bar shows up. This means that, first, I would like to determine how many rows are visible on the screen before the scrollbar shows up, and then create a carousel animation, where the next X rows are showed until all the rows are showed and the animation resets.

**Technologies used:** React JS, Bootstrap table

For the carousel part, I found Bootstrap Carousel to work fine, but the problem is figuring out, how many rows are visible on the screen. How do I determine, how many rows I can display on the screen before the scroll-bar shows up? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I found `window.innerHeight` to work best. After getting the height of the window, I subtract the size of other elements and can determine how many table rows are visible on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be:

1. Create an element in the DOM which would be 100% height (any other possible height will work too). For example:

   `<div id="row-wrapper" style="height: 100%"></div>`
2. Get the height of the element.

   `var availableHeight = document.getElementById('row-wrapper').clientHeight;`
3. Knowing how much height your single row occupies just divide availableHeight and you will know how many rows to render. In case your row height is 30:

`var numberOfRows = Math.floor(availableHeight / 30);`

Comment: I am using React and following [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). The clientHeight variable for the wrapper element is the height of the whole website i.e. all rows and header, even though I set its height to 100%. How do I get the height only of what is visible on the screen?

Comment: set overflow:hidden on your element, furthermore, do the calculations before you poplate the element with the rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you can fill a div until its full. Made a jQuery answer too if someone is interested in that.

I made 2 div's. One with a set height(100% in the example but can be static height too) and inside a growable div that grows with the content.

First it will fill the growable div as long it is smaller then the content div.
The last added element could be bigger then the remaining space. If that happens it removes the last element.

This also works with content with dynamic heights.

Note: When using while loops it's always good to have a backup plan to avoid infinite loops. Therefore I added a max records variable.

**Javascript:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('fill').onclick = function() {
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var growableWrapper = document.getElementById('growableWrapper');
    var maxRecords = 50;

    while ((content.childNodes.length === 0 || parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(growableWrapper).height) < parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content).height)) && growableWrapper.childNodes.length < maxRecords) {
      var newElement = document.createElement("p");
      var newText = document.createTextNode("Test");
      newElement.appendChild(newText);
      growableWrapper.appendChild(newElement);
    }

    if (window.getComputedStyle(growableWrapper).height > window.getComputedStyle(content).height && growableWrapper.childNodes.length > 1) {
      growableWrapper.removeChild(growableWrapper.childNodes[growableWrapper.childNodes.length - 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#fill,
#content {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#growableWrapper {
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="fill">Fill</button>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="growableWrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fill').on('click', function() {
    var content = $('#content');
    var growableWrapper = $('#growableWrapper');
    var maxRecords = 50;
    while ((content.children().length === 0 || growableWrapper.height() < content.height()) && growableWrapper.children().length < maxRecords) {
      growableWrapper.append('<p>test</p>');
    }
    if(growableWrapper.height() > content.height() && growableWrapper.children().length > 1) {
      growableWrapper.children().last().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#fill, #content {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#growableWrapper {
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="fill">Fill</button>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="growableWrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you tagged ReactJS, but a good basis is to always keep your DOM as small as possible. My tactic would be to keep the data in JavaScript and only introduce to the DOM what is absolutely needed.

Below is a simple example showing 10 rows with an offset:

```js
var dummyData = [];
(function populateData() {
  var names = ["Greg", "Jeff", "Bob", "Bruce", "Clark", "Diana"];
  while (dummyData.length < 100000) {
    dummyData.push({
      name: names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)],
      age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    });
  }
})();

function displayData(data, offset, limit) {
  if (offset === void 0) {
    offset = 0;
  }
  if (limit === void 0) {
    limit = data.length;
  }
  var tbody = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
  for (var i = offset; i < (limit + offset); i++) {
    if (i >= data.length) {
      break;
    }
    var person = data[i];
    var tr = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
    tr.innerHTML = "<td>" + i + "</td><td>" + person.name + "</td><td>" + person.age + "</td>";
  }
  return tbody;
}
var pagesize = 10;
var offset = 0;
var offsetInput = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
offsetInput.type = "number";
offsetInput.min = "0";
offsetInput.value = "0";
var table = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
table.style.width = "100%";
table.innerHTML = "<thead><tr><th>Index</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr></thead>";
var tbody = table.appendChild(displayData(dummyData, offset, pagesize));

function update() {
  if (offsetInput.validity.valid) {
    offset = parseInt(offsetInput.value, 10);
    table.removeChild(tbody);
    tbody = displayData(dummyData, offset, pagesize);
    table.appendChild(tbody);
  }
}
offsetInput.addEventListener("change", update);
offsetInput.addEventListener("keyup", update);
```

From here it would be a matter of some CSS tricking and reading the scrollbar to get an offset.

```js
var dummyData = [];
(function populateData() {
  var names = ["Greg", "Jeff", "Bob", "Bruce", "Clark", "Diana"];
  while (dummyData.length < 100) {
    dummyData.push({
      name: names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)],
      age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    });
  }
})();

function displayData(data, offset, limit) {
  if (offset === void 0) {
    offset = 0;
  }
  if (limit === void 0) {
    limit = data.length;
  }
  var tbody = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
  for (var i = offset; i < (limit + offset); i++) {
    if (i >= data.length) {
      break;
    }
    var person = data[i];
    var tr = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
    tr.innerHTML = "<td>" + i + "</td><td>" + person.name + "</td><td>" + person.age + "</td>";
  }
  return tbody;
}
var pagesize = 10;
var offset = 0;
var offsetInput = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
offsetInput.type = "number";
offsetInput.min = "0";
offsetInput.max = "" + (dummyData.length - pagesize);
offsetInput.value = "0";
var outerContainer = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
outerContainer.style.maxHeight = "400px";
outerContainer.style.width = "450px";
outerContainer.style.overflowY = "scroll";
var innerContainer = outerContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
innerContainer.style.height = dummyData.length * 20 + 200 + "px";
var table = innerContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("table"));
table.style.position = "absolute";
table.style.width = "400px";
table.innerHTML = "<thead><tr><th>Index</th><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr></thead>";
var tbody = table.appendChild(displayData(dummyData, offset, pagesize));
var handle;

function update() {
  table.removeChild(tbody);
  tbody = displayData(dummyData, offset, pagesize);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  clearTimeout(handle);
  handle = setTimeout(function() {
    offsetInput.value = offset.toString();
    outerContainer.scrollTop = offset * 20;
  }, 100);
}

function updateInput() {
  if (offsetInput.validity.valid) {
    offset = parseInt(offsetInput.value, 10);
  }
  update();
}

function updateScroll() {
  offset = Math.floor(outerContainer.scrollTop / 20);
  update();
}
outerContainer.addEventListener("scroll", updateScroll);
offsetInput.addEventListener("change", updateInput);
offsetInput.addEventListener("keyup", updateInput);
```